# File upload progress bar in vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, vue-resource

I am trying to develop a Vue.js application.In this regard I am uploading file in this Application. Now I would like to develop a progress bar for that file upload feature. I am trying to follow a tutorial. Here I got `axios` library for upload file. The code is like below

```
axios.post("/upload.php",fd,{
    onUploadProgress: function() {
       //code here
    }
})
```

But I am using `vue-resource`. How can I detect upload progress in `vue-resource`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `vue-resource` will be:

```
this.$http.post('/upload.php', fd, {
  progress(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
      console.log(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
    }
  }
});
```

When you are in development, you won't see the progress unless you throttle the request. Take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/network-conditions) to see how you can throttle the request in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks @Jorj for your reply. I changed Throttle, but I am not getting any output. Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu please try to log before the `if` statement to see if the `progress(e)` is triggered

Comment: Thanks @Jorj for your reply. I tried to log like below `{
                       progress(evt) {
                        console.log('hello')
                        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                            console.log(evt.loaded / evt.total * 100);
                        }
                      }
                    }` . But this is not working. That means `progress()` is not triggered.